# Internal links in IPython notebook stopped working since v 2.2

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I like to create table of contents via markdown for my IPython notebooks to quickly jump between sections.

E.g.,

```
## Sections
- [my header1](#my-header1)
- [my header2](#my-header2)

my header1 (formatted as header)
... some text
my header2 (formatted as header)
... some text
```

and so forth.

What I mean with "formatted as header":

[image]

This is useful for large IPython notebooks:

[image]

The internal links still work when I view the HTML version of the iPython notebook, however, those internal links do not work anymore when I am editing the notebooks since the upgrade to v 2.2. I tested it on multiple machines. Any ideas what causes this problem and how to bring back this useful feature?

Comment: If you can reproduce it in 2.3 or master, feel free to open a bug.

Comment: +Thomas K Oh, I didn't know that 2.3 was already out. I just upgraded and it solved the problem on both machines. It really seems like it WAS a bug in 2.2 but is no solved :)

Comment: Great, bugs that are already fixed are the best kind ;-)